# Edit Code Of Azure Logic App Standard Via VS Code

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

While editing the code of azure logic app standard, the json opens in read-only mode. This happens only for standard logic apps, consumption logic apps work fine in VS Code.

Is there a way to edit the code in VS Code for azure logic apps standard?

Try editing json file of azure logic app standard in VS Code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and please follow the below process which worked for me:

Firstly, I have opened Logic apps Standard workflow and got similar issue as you got `Cannot edit in read-only editor`

[image]

Now, I have Clicked on `File, then clicked on Save` or a simply press `ctrl+S`   and it worked for me.

[image]

Now you can edit code as I am able to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works for me and solves the issue.